# WebDriverWait Selenium approach

Tags: selenium

Regarding the [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) data type, I am assuming that only one instance is needed of such data type, which means I could potentially create a wrapper and allow only one instance creation by using a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) approach.

At the present time I used *thread.sleep* and basically everywhere I need that function to be called I am extending from the class which probably not the best approach. Also of course I should be using WebDriverWait instead of thread. What should the approach be?

So far I created a page object with web elements and a separate service for the logic itself, so now I need also WebDriverWait in every service since it’s a necessary operation.

A cookie window that gets popped up once customer opened the page:

```java
/**
 * acceptCookies -> clickable
 * cookieBanner -> just to identify that cookie component showed up.
 * PageFactory -> will initialize every WebElement variable with a reference to a corresponding element on the actual web page.
 */

public class CookieModal {

    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = ".cookie-accept-all")
    public WebElement acceptCookies;

    public CookieModal(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Then I separated the service (actions):

```java
public class CookieService {

    private final CookieModal cookieModal;

    public CookieService(WebDriver driver) {
        this.cookieModal = new CookieModal(driver);
    }

    public void acceptCookies() {
        cookieModal.acceptCookies.click();
    }
}
```

This must be changed to WebDriverWait, but I also think extending from AbstractPage in every page object is not necessary. Is my structure OK and how should I initialise WebDriverWait?

```java
public class AbstractPage {

    // This is not good as thread sleep is not dynamic and you
    // have to specify time yourself change to webdriver wait

    private AbstractPage microsleep(Integer milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            String error = String.format("Unable to put thread to sleep (requested %d milliseconds).", milliseconds);

            throw new RuntimeException(error, e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public AbstractPage emulateWaitingUser() {
        return microsleep(800);
    }

    public AbstractPage sleep(Integer seconds) {
        return microsleep(1000 * seconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`WebDriverWait` is commonly used with the [ExpectedConditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) class. In that case, you cannot just wait for 800 ms. You need to wait until a condition is met. For example, wait until page title is displayed, or wait until loader icon is not visible, wait until login button is clickable, etc.

That means if you wish to instantiate a wait in an abstract method, you will need to add an unknown (and non-abstract) wait condition. You could just instantiate a general wait object and then add a condition when it is known, but it seems a bit incomplete.

Another idea that comes to my mind is declaring `WebDriverWait` as a field in Cookie Service class and pass it to its methods.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, if i will add WebDriverWait in one service that means i will have to add to every server and for example create an object of it once service constructor is called is that an okey approach ? what about create a singleton class  with static method getInstance ?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium supports integrating explicit waits into page objects. This is achieved by using a special way of how you initialize your page. In your example you are doing this:

```java
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

which involves some basic default way. However, you can add more complexity here, but you get a more effective architecture at the same time.

You can extend the `AjaxElementLocator` class where you will override `isElementUsable` method in the way that would involve any sort of condition and waits. Then you will be initializing your page(s) with that locator through a dedicated `LocatorFactory`. Some example of how to use all that classes you can find [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_page_object_expected_conditions).